# Convert byte to string in Java

Tags: java

I use below code to convert byte to string:

```
System.out.println("string " + Byte.toString((byte)0x63));
```

Why it print "string  99".
How to modify to let it print "string  c"?

Comment: It is impossible to *just* convert a byte to a string. [You must use a character encoding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611455/what-is-character-encoding).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The string ctor is suitable for this conversion:

```
System.out.println("string " + new String(new byte[] {0x63}));
```

Comment: Because gustafc's answer has a very important point: String(byte[]) constructor uses the System default encoding to convert the byte array into String characters. One should not assume that a 0x63 byte value is mapped to the letter 'c'. For example, in UTF-16 the letter 'c' is represented by 2 encoding bytes, not one. This blog post elaborates on this: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Answer (score 47):

```
System.out.println(new String(new byte[]{ (byte)0x63 }, "US-ASCII"));
```

Note especially that converting bytes to Strings *always* involves an encoding. If you do not specify it, you'll be using the platform default encoding, which means the code can break when running in different environments.

Comment: To avoid the checked `UnsupportedEncodingException` thrown by that constructor you'd probably want to pass in [`StandardCharsets.US_ASCII`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html#US_ASCII) instead of using the charset name.

Answer (score 15):

Use char instead of byte:

```
System.out.println("string " + (char)0x63);
```

Or if you want to be a Unicode puritan, you use codepoints:

```
System.out.println("string " + new String(new int[]{ 0x63 }, 0, 1));
```

And if you like the old skool US-ASCII "every byte is a character" idea:

```
System.out.println("string " + new String(new byte[]{ (byte)0x63 },
                                          StandardCharsets.US_ASCII));
```

Avoid using the `String(byte[])` constructor recommended in other answers; it relies on the default charset. Circumstances could arise where `0x63` actually isn't the character *c*.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`printf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29):

```
System.out.printf("string %c\n", 0x63);
```

You can as well create a String with such formatting, using [`String#format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29):

```
String s = String.format("string %c", 0x63);
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use

the **character equivalent to 0x63 is 'c' but byte equivalent to it is 99**

```
System.out.println("byte "+(char)0x63);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to construct a new string out of a byte array. The first element in your `byteArray` should be `0x63`. If you want to add any more letters, make the `byteArray` longer and add them to the next indices.

```
byte[] byteArray = new byte[1];
byteArray[0] = 0x63;

try {
    System.out.println("string " + new String(byteArray, "US-ASCII"));
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    // TODO: Handle exception.
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Note that specifying the encoding will eventually throw an `UnsupportedEncodingException` and you must handle that accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a single byte, just cast the `byte` to a `char` and it should work out to be fine i.e. give a `char` entity corresponding to the codepoint value of the given byte. If not, use the `String` constructor as mentioned elsewhere.

```
char ch = (char)0x63;
System.out.println(ch);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String str = "0x63";
int temp = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(2, 4), 16);
char c = (char)temp;
System.out.print(c);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my version:

```
public String convertBytestoString(InputStream inputStream)
{
    int bytes;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

    bytes = inputStream.read(buffer);
    String stringData = new String(buffer,0,bytes);

    return stringData;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using StringBuilder class in Java:

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte aByte : bytesArray) {
            if (aByte != 0) {
                str.append((char) aByte);
            } else {
                break;
            }
```