# Can you convert a byte from textfield to a string?

Tags: java

I'm trying to get the user input of their age in byte data type in JavaFX. I'm trying to get the data from a textfield but I'm having trouble figuring out how to convert the byte into a string. This is the piece of code I have of it

```
String t = Byte.toString(age1.getText());
```

Is it possible to convert the byte input from textfield into a string?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert byte to string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8654141/convert-byte-to-string-in-java)

Comment: *how to convert the byte into a string* = `String str = new String(bytes);` - see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(byte[])